# Unable to install Visual Studio for Win7 (Unresponsive)

Tags: visual-studio, installation

This might be a stupid question, but I can't solve it for hours and it is killing me.

I'm trying to install visual studio in my lab computer, which runs Win7. The problem is, when I execute visual studio installer, it does not do anything after showing the Visual studio logo and is utterly unresponsive (only a black square pops up). At first, i thought it might be loading for a long time, but after leaving for few hours and still it does nothing.

I've tried to install it using ISO images, or even tried previous versions(2013 and 2012) but failed. 
Formatting would be a simple answer, but it is practically impossible since it is used by multiple members in our lab, so I can't occupy it for too long to format and installing all other existing software.

How can I solve this problem? 
Thank you for even reading this question. I would appreciate even more if I can get an answer!

[image]

Comment: is your Windows 7 up to date?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, I installed all the updates, and still it isn't working.

Comment: also update the GPU driver. The setup is based on WPF so also new drivers are recommend.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Wow it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer so tat you can accept it and "close" the question

Answer (score 0):

You should install all Windows Updates and also update the GPU driver. The setup is based on [Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) which uses GPU to accelerate the UI so also up to date drivers are recommend.